# NetSuite case ageing notification

Tags: case, netsuite

Below question is related to NetSuite Support Module.

We want to send an email notification to the support rep assigned to the case if the time since last modification of the case has exceeded 48 hours. This notification needs to be sent for each case as soon as it ages over 48 hours since last modification,

I tried a saved search notifiaction, but that does not work as the case which exceeds 48 hours is not a new record.

I am not able to figure out what the trigger would be for a workflow or a script to make this notification work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Use a workflow
- make initiation "Scheduled"
- use a condition that the Case is not closed or whatever works for you
- under Saved Search set up a search that ids cases older than 48 hours
- the saved search will run every half an hour and pick up your aging cases.

To finish this you need to decide if the same case will get another every half an hour until it's been dealt with. If so the workflow can end when the email goes out. If not then the workflow needs to go into some state waiting for the next escalation or waiting for some delay until you can ping the assignee again.